# iphone view controller methods not being called but view shows

Tags: iphone, uitableview, view, uiviewcontroller, breakpoints

I have a navigation controller with a UITableView which when goes to another view when a row is selected. When this loads the breakpoints get hit.
Good so far.
When I hit the back button, the table view appears fine, with data. 
However, even though I have breakpoints enabled in the viewcontroller, none get hit like when it originally loaded! But yet, the data loads fine. The only breakpoint that registers now is when I click on a row (didSelectRowAtIndexPath).

Answer (score 0):

Where are the breakpoints set that you are expecting it to break?

Perhaps you need to call the following in the viewWillAppear method...

```
[self.table reloadData];
```

Answer (score 0):

It would depend on where your breakpoint is actually located. If you have a breakpoint in viewDidLoad method, then it will only be called once when the view is first created. When you go back from another view, the view is not loaded again. So the breakpoint will not hit. However, viewWillAppear method will be called.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a navigation controller here. Navigation controller holds a navigation stack, which includes UIViews on top of each other, with the visible one on the top.

Now, let's say the table view was loaded, then you move to another (which is now the topmost view in the navigation stack). Note - the table view is not gone. It's there, just under the view you are currently presenting.

Thus, when you move back to the table view, it is not reloaded, because it was never gone (released), just hidden.

There are exceptions to the above, and sometimes a view which is not presented on screen will be released (low memory scenarios situations, for example), but you can't count on it.

The [UINavigationController Class Referance](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) explains this concept very well.